# Add a default value for a json property when it doesn't exist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So I'm trying to edit this rss feed with these 2 functions because of the `media:content` property which I have had no luck accessing directly.  the functions I have below work for creating a new value called `mediaContent` which I can then easily access.  The issue is in the rss feed not all objects will have `media:content` and I want to add a default value for the objects that don't have that property so I have consistency in my objects.  Otherwise I end up with undefined on on some of `mediaContent` in my new object.  I wanted to start just added a default value in when `media:content` is not present in the object but these ||'s are not working as I would have expected.  How can I get my `else if` to punch in a default value if `media:content` does not exist?  I'm probably missing something easy.

```
function getMediaContent(value) {
    for (var i in value) {
        if (i === "media:content") {
            console.log("MC::", i)
            return value[i].$;
        } else if (i !== "title" || i !== "link" || i !== "pubDate" || i !== "isoDate" || i !== "guid" || i !== "contentSnippet" || i !== "content") {
            debugger;
            return "no media content"
        }
    }
}

function getNewsLinks() {
    return newsItems.map(value => ({
        value,
        mediaContent: getMediaContent(value)
    }))
}
```

SOLUTION (based on accepted answer)

```
    function getMediaContent(value) {
        return "media:content" in value ? value["media:content"].$ : "no media content";

    }
```

works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: I would think `return "media:content" in value ? value["media:content"].$ : "no media content";` would work, but I'm not sure what `value` is...

Comment: That might be the easy thing I been missing.  Let me check that.

Comment: That's it.  I don't even need these functions.  If you post an answer.  I will glady accept it.  I don't need to derive a new set of objects with property mediaContent added.  I can just access like your suggesting from original RSS feed using `["media:content"].$` and be done with all this.

Comment: `return value['media:content'] || 'no media content';`

Comment: @DrewReese There's the little wrinkle of the `$` property. You could use `return value['media:content'] && value['media:content'].$ || 'no media content';`, but that seems just as verbose.

Comment: Ah, good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're just looking to see if a property exists on an object, you can use the `in` operator:

```
function getMediaContent(value) {
  return "media:content" in value ? value["media:content"].$ : "no media content";
}
```

That checks if the property exists, and if so, gets the value of its `$` property. Otherwise, returns the default value.

Comment: This works perfect if I want to do the checks for undefined.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar and optionally it would work for multi-layered JSON  objects. Here is the function I use:

```
function getFromJSON(obj, ...args) {
    for (const arg of args) {
        if (!Array.isArray(arg)) {
            if (arg in obj) {
                obj = obj[arg]
            } else {
                return `${arg} not found in JSON`;
            }
        } else {
            for (const argOpt of arg) {
                if (argOpt in obj) {
                    obj = obj[argOpt]
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj
}
```

In addition, you can pass multiple keys in an array if you want to get the value of whichever exists.